# It's a Hypothesis about the Beginning of the universe

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, astrophysics, big-bang, singularities

Let's take a piece of paper and plot a couple of dots in it. If we shrink the paper infinitely, at some point it would reach a state of infinite density, that is; a Singularity.
But even at that state, if we could look infinity close, we will be able to see the dots in it, right? 
What I'm trying to prove is, even when the universe was at a singularity, the entire universe should have existed inside that singularity.
I know it sounds crazy, but that singularity could have all space and time inside it. Every single atom in the universe could have been present inside that singularity.
Thus, that singularity cannot be the beginning of the universe and time.

Is this possible?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Physics SE. Look around, and take the [tour]. As it stands, your question is mostly philosophical. You may wish to (1) search this site for 'singularity' and see if the questions/answers there are useful, and (2) edit your question in light of 1 to by physics-based, not metaphysical.

Comment: You should also search for 'big bang'.  Plus you are assuming that the matter/energy balance of the universe is constant: "every single atom."  And there is no justifying statement for your last sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you are going wrong is in thinking that the singularity is some well defined thing that is described by the laws of physics. In fact the exact opposite is true.

In general relativity the geometry of spacetime is described by an object (strictly speaking a tensor field) that is defined over all of spacetime i.e. at all points in the universe at all times. However the singularity is not part of the universe and the metric is not defined there. The solution describing an expanding universe, the [FLRW metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann%E2%80%93Lema%C3%AEtre%E2%80%93Robertson%E2%80%93Walker_metric), is defined for all times $t > 0$ but is not defined at $t = 0$. The $t = 0$ limit is what we call the Big Bang, but it's essential to understand that the Big Bang is the limit of $t \rightarrow 0$ and is not part of the universe.

So it makes neither physical nor mathematical sense to talk about taking the universe at time zero and using an infinite magnification to study it. In fact wherever you encounter an infinity in physics it usually means the theory you're working with no longer applies. One of the long term goals of physics is to find a theory that describes what happens in the limit of $t \rightarrow 0$. We expect that this new theory will replace the singularity by some structure that is finite, but right now we have no idea what that new theory will look like.